# How to shuffle cards within a Card object with Math.random()

Tags: java

So the problem is I am not getting any card rank or value of card such as a number 2-14 and my characters 'C', 'D', 'H', 'S' seem to get shuffled.

How would I go about shuffling an object containing

```
new Card(int, char)
```

with characters 'C', 'D', 'H', 'S' which represent the cards suit.

This code below does not seem to work as in saving any rank numbers.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 51; i++)           
cards[i] = new Card((int)Math.random() * 52, 'D');
```

An example of how the shuffling should work if card [14] randomly generates integer 35, then card[14] would swap with card[35].

```
public void shuffle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 51; i++)           
        cards[i] = new Card((int)Math.random() * 52, 'D');

    for (int i = 0; i <= 51; i++) {     
        Card temp = cards[i];
        for (int j = 0; j <= 51; j++) {
            cards[i] = cards[j];
            cards[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `(int) Math.random() * 52` will only cast `Math.random()` to an int, thus always making it 0. You should use parentheses like this: `(int) (Math.random() * 52)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you first create the deck, then shuffle it.

```
// Create deck
Card[] cards = new Card[52];
int i = 0;
for (int v = 2; v <= 14; v++)
    for (char s : "CDHS".toCharArray())
        cards[i++] = new Card(v, s);

// Shuffle
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cards));
```

Comment: You have a typo in line 2: `Chard`.

Comment: Why even create an array at all? Also, maybe you could explain how the sorted result is usable since you never assign the list that you sort in-place.

Comment: *Why even create an array at all?* - What do you mean? *since you never assign the list that you sort in-place.* - Not sure what you mean here either? The `Arrays.asList` returns a List-view of the array, so `Collections.shuffle` will indeed shuffle the array.

Comment: @aioobe To the first part: instead of creating an array and converting it into a list, you can just create a list right away. The array is unnecessary. About the second part, never mind, I was wrong on that. `Arrays.asList` provides a list that propagates changes to the array it is backed by.

Comment: The OP used an array, that's why I went with an array. And frankly, if it's a fixed size list like this, and if you don't need any List-functions then I think using an array is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list which contains all of the cards deck.

Create a loop to random some number between zero and the list side, each time you're getting a number just remove this item from the list and put it in some shuffeld list.

You can also use:

```
Collections.shuffle(yourList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `ArrayList` instead of an array and then use

```
List<Card> myCards = new ArrayList<>();
//Add your cards
Collections.shuffle(myCards);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.public void shuffle()
2.{
3.for (int i = 0; i <= 51; i++)           
4.    cards[i] = new Card((int)Math.random() * 52, 'D');

5.for (int i = 0; i <= 51; i++) {     
6.    Card temp = cards[i];
7.    for (int j = 0; j <= 51; j++) {
8.        cards[i] = cards[j];
9.        cards[j] = temp;
    }
}
}
```

At the first iteration inside the j-loop, you are setting every card[0-52] as temp. Hence you are ending up copying first card to all of them.

Best solution here would be to use the existing shuffle functionality from collections

```
List<Card> myCards = new ArrayList<>();
//Add your cards
Collections.shuffle(myCards);
```